# Quarto Not Rendering

Tags: r, rstudio, quarto

My quarto documents have stopped rendering suddenly. I have reinstalled RStudio and the quarto package, but this issue persists.

When I open a new quarto document, I no longer see the boilerplate material in the new document. The document is empty as if I had selected `Create Empty Document`, but I haven't.

Then, the document renders when all I include is raw text, but when I include an `r` code chunk, I get the following message.

```
Error in xfun::normalize_path(path, ..., must_work = must_work, resolve_symlink = FALSE) : 
  unused argument (resolve_symlink = FALSE)
Calls: .main ... execute -> setwd -> dirname -> <Anonymous> -> normalize_path
Execution halted
```

Here is the quarto document I'm attempting to render.

````
---
title: "Testing"
---

```{r}
mtcars |> print()
```
````

---

Here is my session info:

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9      ps_1.7.2        digest_0.6.30   later_1.3.0    
 [5] jsonlite_1.8.4  pacman_0.5.1    evaluate_0.20   zip_2.2.2      
 [9] rlang_1.0.6     cli_3.4.1       rstudioapi_0.14 fs_1.5.2       
[13] rmarkdown_2.20  tools_4.2.2     yaml_2.3.6      xfun_0.35      
[17] fastmap_1.1.0   parallel_4.2.2  compiler_4.2.2  processx_3.8.0 
[21] htmltools_0.5.4 knitr_1.41      quarto_1.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue with knitr, this worked for me:

- Remove the package "xfun" from the packages section, then reinstall it immediately after.

I'd tried changing the root install for R and everything. Turns out it was just xfun being weird.

Found the solution on the [Posit Community forum](https://community.rstudio.com/t/im-not-able-to-knit-after-i-install-new-version-of-r-rstudio-and-rtools/158029).

Comment: Great. Funny, I updated the xfun package but didn't think to uninstall and reinstall the package.  This solved my issue.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any spaces in the filename or file path? That was preventing me from rendering for a bit.

Comment: Nope, no spaces in the filename, and the file is in the root of the working directory.  It occurs whether I'm in a project or not; and still occurs when I'm working in just the Windows Documents folder. Strange.