# knitting in rmarkdown yields error from xfun package

Tags: r, markdown

I am getting the following error whilst using R Markdown.

I have not used RStudio for a while, so I updated to the latest version and I have updated all packages.

I have tried removing `xfun` and reinstalling it. I always get this error when trying to knit just the default R Markdown. Any ideas gratefully appreciated!

```
Error in xfun::normalize_path(path, ..., must_work = must_work, resolve_symlink = FALSE) : 
  unused argument (resolve_symlink = FALSE)
Calls: <Anonymous> -> normalize_path
Execution halted
```

oaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] xfun_0.30          tidyselect_1.1.2   nortest_1.0-4      purrr_0.3.4 [5] olsrr_0.5.3        lattice_0.20-41    carData_3.0-5      colorspace_2.0-3 [9] vctrs_0.3.8        generics_0.1.3     htmltools_0.5.1.1  viridisLite_0.4.1 [13] yaml_2.3.5         utf8_1.2.1         plotly_4.10.1      rlang_1.0.2 [17] ggpubr_0.4.0       pillar_1.8.1       glue_1.4.2         DBI_1.1.3 [21] RColorBrewer_1.1-3 uuid_1.1-0         lifecycle_1.0.1    plyr_1.8.7 [25] munsell_0.5.0      ggsignif_0.6.4     gtable_0.3.1       zip_2.2.0 [29] htmlwidgets_1.5.4  evaluate_0.20      knitr_1.39         GGally_2.1.2 [33] fansi_0.5.0        broom_1.0.3        Rcpp_1.0.8.3       openssl_2.0.0 [37] backports_1.4.1    scales_1.2.1       jsonlite_1.8.0     abind_1.4-5 [41] gridExtra_2.3      ggplot2_3.3.6      askpass_1.1        digest_0.6.27 [45] rstatix_0.7.2      dplyr_1.0.6        grid_4.0.3         cli_3.2.0 [49] tools_4.0.3        magrittr_2.0.1     goftest_1.2-3      lazyeval_0.2.2 [53] tibble_3.1.2       tidyr_1.2.0        car_3.1-1          pkgconfig_2.0.3 [57] ellipsis_0.3.2     Matrix_1.4-1       data.table_1.14.2  xml2_1.3.3 [61] rmarkdown_2.20     rstudioapi_0.14    assertthat_0.2.1   reshape_0.8.9 [65] officer_0.6.0      httr_1.4.5         R6_2.5.1           compiler_4.0.3

Comment: You may want to update your question with `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: i have added sessioninfo()

Comment: But somehow you missed the important part.

Comment: What is the important part

Comment: R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base

Comment: Your R is outdated, you also should update R, not just RStudio.

Comment: A clean edit of your question with your `sessionInfo()` would look much nicer. If you use a clean session, there are not so much namespaces loaded, interesting is the upper part that states your OS and R version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quarto Not Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75215294/quarto-not-rendering)